# SQL to Linq conversion left outer join

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert this SQL statement into LINQ

```
SELECT     
  a.UserId, b.Date, a.Value1
FROM         
  web.Table2 AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  web.Table1 AS a 
ON 
  b.Date = a.CreateDate AND UserId = 1
```

This is what I have that is not working:

```
Dim query = From a In ctx.Table1 _
        Group Join b In ctx.Table2 On b.Date Equals a.CreateDate Into group1 = Group
        From x In group1.DefaultIfEmpty() _
        Where ls.UserId = 1 _
        Select a.UserId, x.Date, a.Value1
```

Comment: Why isn't it working?  Wrong results or Error?  If error, please post entire error message... thanks

Comment: Wrong results, does not perform a proper left outer join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always directly execute your query in LINQ To SQL, e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> results = db.ExecuteQuery<MyClass>(@"
    SELECT a.UserId, b.Date, a.Value1 
    FROM web.Table2 AS b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN web.Table1 AS a ON b.Date = a.CreateDate 
        AND UserId = 1");
```

Comment: Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Table1) = ctx.ExecuteQuery(Of Table1)(@"SELECT a.UserId, b.Date, a.Value1 FROM web.Table2 AS b LEFT OUTER JOIN web.Table1 AS a ON b.Date = a.CreateDate AND UserId = 1")

Comment: What is the @ sign for? Getting an error, expression expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be (check alias b, you were using x)

```
Dim query = From a In ctx.Table1 _
        Join b In ctx.Table2 _ 
        On b.Date Equals a.CreateDate Into group1 = Group _
        Where a.UserId = 1 _
        From b In group1.DefaultIfEmpty() _            
        Select a.UserId, b.Date, a.Value1
```

Comment: I get this error: 'b' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

Comment: Also, did you mean to remove group join and replace with a regular join?  That causes more errors.